# Paper.JS Framework "Selection Outlines"

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, drawing, paperjs

Anybody know how I can easily customize "Selection Outlines" in paper.js. ". Paper.js draws the visual outlines of selected items on top of my Circle and I want to cutomize the size and color of this outlines.
for example:

```
var myCircle = new Path.Circle(new Point(100, 70), 50); 
myCircle.strokeColor = 'black'; 
myCircle.selected = true;
```

Answer (score 5):

Right now you are able to assign selectedColor property for your Circle with Color object like this:

```
var myCircle = new Path.Circle(new Point(100, 70), 50);
myCircle.selectedColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 1); // this is PaperJS color object
myCircle.selected = true;
```

Check out http://paperjs.org/reference/item/#selectedcolor